# Getting struct redefinition error while using #pragma once in header and cpp files

Tags: c++

Title. I'm using pragma once in all relevant files but I'm still getting this error. I'd appreciate any help.

Event.h:

```
    //This file is relevant to the others.
    #pragma once
    enum QueueType {Interactive, Noninteractive};
    enum EventType {Start, Core, SSD, TTY};

    struct Event {

        //Event info
        int time;
        EventType e;
        int PID;
        QueueType q;
    };
```

Queue.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "Event.h"

//Problem code
struct nodeType {
    Event info;
    nodeType *link;
};
//Everything else in the file is basic Queue functions. Will provide if needed.
```

PriorityQueue.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "Event.h"


struct nodeType {
    Event info;
    nodeType *link;
};
//Also contains Priority Queue functions
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <assert.h>
#include "Event.h"
#include "Queue.h"
#include "PriorityQueue.h"
using namespace std;

//Also includes some test code
```

In the implementation files for Queue.h and PriorityQueue.h I use pragma once and include their respective header files as well as iostream and assert. I include using namespace std cause I'm lazy. All the other research I've done seemed to come down to people not using include guards which I don't think is the problem here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined the struct `nodeType` twice, in two different headers. This will cause your error. Only define it in one header, or if they're meant to be different types, either give them different names or put them in separate `namespace`s.

`#pragma once` or include guards only prevent multiple inclusions of the particular header; if you violate the One Definition Rule in the way you are currently doing so include guards won't save you.

Comment: Why is that the case? The respective files for Queue and PriorityQueue don't reference each other and they don't interact until I put them both in main.

Comment: `#include` works by effectively copy/pasting the contents of the named file in place. When both files are copied in, then the compiler will see both definitions of `nodeType`. Also note that you aren't allowed two different types with the same name, even if they're never shared in a single file; in this case the contents of both `nodeType`s are identical so you don't run into this problem, but if you change one your program will be ill-formed.

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you for your help!